# How do I use dhcpd option 121 with a Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, dhcp

Does anyone know how to us dhcpd option 121 correctly with the Cisco ASA?

I would like to provide a static route to hosts

example

```
Destination Network   Destination Mask  Via IP
192.168.168.0         255.255.255.0     192.168.201.254
```

I tried doing the hex calculator, but I do not this either of these are right

24c0a8a800c0a8a801
ffffff00c0a8a800c0a8c9fe

Thanks

Comment: What DHCP has anything to do with routing?
Just set him the GW and let your router/ASA to do the job

Comment: just so you know, if you check a couple days ago in the chat for this site I wrote a decent length monologue on how people should stop using ASA's as routers and use them as security appliances (what they were built for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco ASA dhcp server supports the options listed in rfc 2132 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132.txt
So you have only option 33, but it is only working with hosts and not subnets.

Comment: Do you know how to set the option correct for a specific host. Let's say the host is 192.168.168.50 do you know how to specify the option correctly? Thanks

Comment: Try:
dhcpd option 33 ip IP_OF_HOST IP_OF_GW